# automatically code binary variables as factors?

Tags: r, boolean, r-factor

I have a question: is there a R function to automatically code binary variables as factors?

I have a tibble with over 80 variables (columns), many of which are of a boolean nature (0, 1 and NAs) that R imported as *numeric*. As I would like to avoid transforming them manually into *factors*, I wondered if there was a function capable of automatically detect *binary numeric variables* in a `data.frame` (or a `tibble`) and change them into factors? I could create such a function myself, but if it already exists, why bother?

Comment: Perhaps `purrr::map_df(df, as.factor)` ?

Comment: Do you need something like `function(x) { if(all(x %in% c(0, 1, NA)) as.factor(x); x }` ?

Comment: You could set the colClasses when importing, e.g.: `x <- read.table(..., colClasses = "factor")`

Comment: @markus Yes, probably something like that. Not all my columns are binary variables (I also have continuous variables and multiple level factors). Allan I do not know this map_df function, but I will look at it. Thank you for your replies!

Comment: I'm not sure the [binary-data] tag is really appropriate ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below we assume that a column is regarded as binary as long as

- it is not all NA and
- aside from NAs it is made up only of numeric 0 and 1 values.

Note that a column which is entirely 0 and NA or entirely 1 and NA is regarded as binary but if that is undesirable we show how to change the code to require that binary columns have both 0 and 1.

First define a function `is_binary` that defines whether a column is to be regarded as binary or not.  This function can be changed if you want to change the definition of binary.  In particular change 1:2 to 2 in the code below if a column must have both 0 and 1 in order to consider it as binary.  Other definitions are possible if needed.

Next apply `is_binary` to each column returning a logical vector `ok` with one component per column that is TRUE if that column is binary or FALSE otherwise.

In the line computing the answer `DF2` we apply `factor` to each binary column using the argument `levels = 0:1` to ensure that columns that only have 0's or only have 1's still have both levels.

No packages are used.

```
DF <- data.frame(a = c(0:1, NA), b = 1:3, c = NA, d = 0) # test data frame

is_binary <- function(x) {
  x0 <- na.omit(x)
  is.numeric(x) && length(unique(x0)) %in% 1:2 && all(x0 %in% 0:1)
}
ok <- sapply(DF, is_binary)
DF2 <- replace(DF, ok, lapply(DF[ok], factor, levels = 0:1))

str(DF2)
## 'data.frame':   3 obs. of  4 variables:
##  $ a: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 2 NA
##  $ b: int  1 2 3
##  $ c: logi  NA NA NA
##  $ d: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1
```

We could alternately use dplyr with `is_binary` like this:

```
DF %>% mutate(across(where(is_binary), ~ factor(., levels = 0:1)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `where` tidyselect function:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  mutate(across(where(~all(unique(.[!is.na(.)]) %in% c("0","1"))), as.factor))
```

The argument of `where` must be a function which returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`. Here I use `unique` to ensure all of the values are `0` or `1`. Using `%in%` helps with the edge case where the binary variable is actually encoded in a character vector. Since `0L %in% "0"`, `0 %in% "0"`, and `"0" %in% "0"` all evaluate `TRUE`.

Then across applies `as.factor` to columns only if the function provided to `where` evaluates `TRUE`.

```
data %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(across(everything(), class))
#       V1      V2      V3      V4      V5      V6      V7      V8      V9     V10
#1 numeric numeric numeric numeric numeric numeric numeric numeric numeric numeric

data %>%
  mutate(across(where(~all(unique(.[!is.na(.)]) %in% c("0","1"))), as.factor)) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(across(everything(), class))
#      V1     V2     V3     V4     V5      V6      V7      V8      V9     V10
#1 factor factor factor factor factor numeric numeric numeric numeric numeric
```

Some sample data:

```
data <- setNames(as.data.frame(cbind(replicate(5,sample(c(0,1,NA),10, replace = TRUE)),
                                     replicate(5,runif(10,0,100)))),paste0("V",1:10))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you like the tidyverse, then combining @G.Grothendieck's `is_binary()` with `mutate_if` works well.

```
library(dplyr)
DF <- data.frame(a = c(0:1, NA), b = 1:3, c = NA, d = 0) # test data frame
is_binary <- function(x) {
 x0 <- na.omit(x)
 length(unique(x0)) %in% 1:2 && all(x0 %in% 0:1)
}
DF %>% mutate_if(is_binary, factor)
```